# Opentype fonts: A few wrong glyphs with current lualatex

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, opentype

As a happy user of TeXLive 2015, I came across a strange problem. With the current version (kept up-to-date with tlmgr), strange glyph substitutions occur with CronosPro and MinionPro, but not with other OTF fonts. The file

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{MinionPro-Regular}
    \setsansfont{CronosPro-Regular}
    \begin{document}
    \textsf{Test: \textsc{test.}}
    Test: \textsc{test.}
    \end{document}
```

is set to a PDF which shows `"` instead of `:` after the words `Test`. Switching to TeXLive 2014 (by changing the PATH environment appropriately) leads to correct PDFs, and so does using XeLaTeX instead of LuaLatex.

I'd appreciate any hint on what mistake I might make.

Comment: You’re not making a mistake: you’ve been bitten by the bug reported at https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/222 and https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/309

Comment: The version of `luaotfload` which has just been uploaded to CTAN (2.6-fix-4  2015-12-23) is supposed to fix this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. With the current TeXLive update via tlmgr, which brought luaotfload 39193, glyphs come as expected, and TeX is working like a charm again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to a software bug and has been solved by an update

Comment: The bug is solved and the example given in my original posting now leads to a PDF as expected. Please close the question. Thank you.